# How to render sqlite3 data into HTML tables using {{#each}}

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I am following a node.js tutorial but instead of using mongodb I am trying out sqlite. I have everything working. I am able to store data into the sqlite database but now I need to display it in an HTML table. Here's my code for retrieving data from a table called News

```
index: (req,res) => {
    let sql = 'SELECT *'
        sql += 'FROM News'

        db.all(sql, [], (error, rows) => {
            if (error){
                console.log(error);
            }
            res.send(rows);
            //res.redirect('admin/index');

        });

    },
```

Now I am able to send this row to the browser using

```
res.send(rows)
```

Here is my html code,

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="alert alert-secondary text-center">
  <h1>ALL POSTS</h1>
</div>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead class="bg-dark text-center">
    <tr class="text-white">
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Content</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="text-center">
    {{#each this}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{id}}</td>
      <td>{{title}}</td>
      <td>{{content}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I tried to use res.render after res.send to render the tables but it throw error

```
Cannot set headers after they are sent to client.
```

How do I do this solve this? I can see the data in my browser now I want to render it in my table.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I figured it out. You have to render the page and send data in the same res.render(). So this is what you have to do,

```
//just remove the 
res.send(rows);
//and replace it with
res.render('admin/index', {news:rows});
```

and replace with in your html/handlebars

```
{{#each news}}
```